# unexpected ')', which I can not figure out

Tags: r, nested

I am getting the following error. I can not figure out what is missing, as I seem to have all my brackets matched up.

> Error: unexpected ')' in:
>   "{
>   if (grepl(propertiesData[x,'city'],population[z,'NAME'],ignore.case=TRUE) & (propertiesData[x,'stateLong']==population[z,'STATENAME')"

Here is the code of the loop:

```
for (z in c(1:nrow(population)))
{
    if (grepl(propertiesData[x,'city'],population[z,'NAME'],ignore.case=TRUE) & (propertiesData[x,'stateLong']==population[z,'STATENAME'))
    {
        propertiesData[x,'population']=population[z,'POP_2009']
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you use an IDE that will help you with your syntax. Your time is too precious to spend it on stuff like this. I recommend RStudio or Eclipse+StatET plugin.

Comment: R is telling you exactly what is wrong so this is way too obvious

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
==population[z,'STATENAME'))
```

Seems like you forgot the closing bracket. Add it in and see what happens:

```
==population[z,'STATENAME']))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing one `]` at the end of line.

...==population[z,'STATENAME'**]** ))

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "]" at the end : (propertiesData[x,'stateLong']==population[z,'STATENAME']))